# "square yards" and "all dickey"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does it mean "square yards" and "all dickey" in (presumably) "pirate languague"?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Both _slack in stays_ and _square the yards_ are terms from sailing, not piracy in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, combining

> [**square**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/square)
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **4.1** Adopt a posture of defence.

with

> [**yard**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/yard)
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **2** A cylindrical spar, tapering to each end, slung across a ship's mast for a sail to hang from.

we get

- **square yards** – prepare the ship for fighting

---

For the second question, the alternate spelling of **dickey** is

> **dicky**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> not strong, healthy, or functioning reliably.

---

The opponent is falling from the sky, so I suppose in the context the author means

- I will easily win our battle; you are not ready and the outcome is a foregone conclusion.